# Identifying this type of Koch Snowflake

Tags: calculus, area

I'm attempting to create a summation for the area of a variation of a classic Koch Snowflake. Unfortunately, I'm having difficulty with this, and I can't find anything similar to it on the internet.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The second step of the snowflake (level 1) looks very similar to the construction of an anti-snowflake, but the step immediately afterwards is completely different. Is the snowflake alternating removing and adding possibly? I've been working at this for several days and I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: No snowflake visible on your image...

Comment: @JeanMarie I suppose it isn't technically a snowflake by definition, but it follows the same method of construction as the other Koch variations.

Comment: I imagine you are in the course of writing a program. Don't you have screenshots ?

Comment: Yes, it’s alternately removing and adding, or, if you prefer, pushing in and pushing out. This is clear if you superimpose each stage on the previous one.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Pictures of the first six stages are visible at the OP’s link.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Oh yes ! Thank you, I moved to the right screen instead of going down. Beautiful ! I don't advise you to move to the right (horrible).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah thank you, never thought about superimposing the images like that. I quickly used WolframAlpha to estimate the convergence of the area to be (5*sqrt(3)/26), which is slightly less than the original area, which seems reasonable. (And haha, no problem @JeanMarie)

Answer (score 1):

The area is easily found by series.   The one shown converges to 10/13 the area of the starting triangle.   If you start by pushing out you end up at 16/13 instead.